# All Android Studio projects saying that they're already on Github

Tags: android, android-studio, github

I'm attempting to push my projects up to Github. I initially created a repo for one and deleted it from my Github. Now, each of my projects are getting an error that reads that they're already on Github, despite the fact that they're not. I even created a new test project and it is getting the same error.

Am I missing a global config that is affecting all of my android studio projects?

EDIT: Added Screenshot below

[image: Screenshot]

The warning reads:

> Project is Already on GitHub
>
> Can't connect to repository from configured remote. You could want to check .git config. Do you want to proceed anyway?
>
> No/Yes

Comment: Does the error say they are in github or they that the local repository that you cloned already exists? Please [edit] your question to include the text or screenshot of the error.

Comment: Hi @cricket_007, sorry. Added a screenshot of what I'm seeing.

Comment: I see. I think the title of that dialog is wrong. The text beneath it seems more reasonable as it says you have a remote configured already in the `.git/` directory of the folder you are using (and *that* does not exist in Github). These dot-folders are hidden by default on most OS's. I see you are using a Mac, so you may navigate to that folder in the terminal and use `ls -la` to see the `.git` folder

Comment: Awesome, @cricket_007, I do see that .git folder in terminal. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, so if you delete that folder, it should allow you to re-clone a Github repository. I typically use the terminal for all git related tasks anyways.

Comment: I figured out that Android Studio was creating a git root in my user folder. I deleted it and recreated it in the appropriate project folder and everything is working well now. Thanks for all of your help, @cricket_007